# Can a horcrux hold the souls of two different people?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

According to Harry Potter Wikia, A Horcrux **is an object in which a Dark wizard or witch has hidden a fragment of his or her soul for the purpose of attaining immortality.**

So the question is, is it possible for two Dark Wizards to split their soul and place the broken piece into the same object (e.g. a diary).

We have seen that more than one soul can exist in a body, as Harry had his own soul along with a piece of Voldemort's soul inside his body, and when Voldemort possessed Quirrell, Quirrell had his own soul along with Voldemort's mangled soul.

So can more than one fragment of a soul live in one object. Could multiple people make the same object their horcrux?

Comment: So... it's bad enough to make magical artifacts into semi-sentient pieces of evil... but now we need to make them bipolar as well?  For laughs?

Comment: @Radhil I like how you use the word bipolar and yes. Do you think that if the two dark wizards were enemies, their souls would fight for dominancy inside the object and force the weaker soul fragment out of the object?

Comment: I very much doubt it would happen in the first place, as a dark wizard trying to create the most important treasure of their lives is not going to trust any random object without scrying, probing, and making sure no other magic but theirs is in play.  That's apart from whether or not a horcrux would have protections specifically preventing it from being reused as a vessel from someone else.  Apart from *all that*... you want Thunderdome with souls.  Fight for dominancy? Sure, why not.  Force each other out? Less likely, magic holding them in is the point.

Comment: I could see it being part of a REALLY messy Dark Wizard wedding ceremony...

Comment: @Radhil however, Voldemort used the Resurrection Stone ring to embed his horcrux in it without realizing its value

Comment: @TimSparrow - good point.

Answer (score 8):

## We... don't know.

This isn't specifically mentioned in the books, and I can't find anything on Pottermore or any other various canon works (*Fantastic Beasts* etc).

My guess is that it's possible, but nobody would want to. Why?

Take the scene with Ron and the locket. The Horcrux tries to take him over, turn him against Harry and Hermione. If you have two fragments in the same thing, which peice of soul would it do that for? If the two wizards who put the soul in have conflicting interests, how would it decide?

If someone is going after the Horcruxes of the other person, your Horcrux gets destroyed also if they find it.

More people know where your Horcruxes are if you share containers.

Why do I think it's possible? Because of the examples in the question - there are several instances of more than one soul in one body. Why should it be different for other objects?

Tl:dr:

## It's not confirmed, but my guess is that it's possible but nobody would do it.

Comment: It is possible to use it as some form of "Mutual assured destruction". Bad wizard A and bad wizard B want to concentrate on those filthy aurors, but to focus their "badness" on the aurors they have to avoid being backstabbed by the other. By "sharing" a Horcux (sounds way more romantic then intended) they have an insurance, since normal bad wizards have only one Horcrux.

Comment: @IIOIOOO *normal* Dark wizards have *zero* Horcruces, in point of fact - but overall I think your point stands.

Answer (score 1):

### I think the answer here is a clear 'no'.

**The part below contains spoilers to multiple Harry Potter books.**

Tom Riddle himself explained at the graveyard that after being hit by the rebound of his killing curse, he was torn out of his body and used to live in animals and later in Quirrel. He needed unicorn blood to stay alive at that time (as you may remember from *Philosopher's Stone*).

This points toward saying that two souls cannot live in one object (in these examples, living things) for a long time without hurting or even killing the weaker soul.

In the prophecy it is said that one cannot live without the other dying, this may (I repeat, may as I am merely speculating) mean that Harry or Tom's soul piece in Harry, would die either way even if Harry was to turn away. By giving in to Tom in the end he made sure the right piece, the weaker piece that could not give in, was killed.

This would suggest that Nagini would not be able to grow very old either unless if the horcrux would literally take over. To strengthen this claim, Dumbledore told Harry he suspected the snake of being a horcrux as Tom had exceptional control over the snake, even for being a parselmouth (HP and the halfblood prince). This would be the case if his soul was the one in control.

This same reasoning  could apply for Ginny getting weaker while Tom-in-the-diary became stronger and she would ultimately die in order to give him the strength to rise up again (*Chamber of Secrets*) in the chamber. But as this does not *literally* contain two souls in one object as Ginny was not split so far as we know (though she may have been partly drained into the diary, we know that Tom-in-the-diary could take over her body for short times at that point).

I am sorry for not using the specific quotes from the books but I hope this answers your question.